# Count how many times left mouse button is clicked

Tags: python, event-handling

The code snippet works perfectly fine, but someone said, and I quote, "this is some of the weirdest code i've seen", so I'd just like any advice for it. It's supposed to count the amount of times I click my left mouse button.

Is there anyway to make it more concise?

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='mouseLog.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

mouseCount = 0
#def on_move(x, y):
    #print('Mouse moved to ({0}, {1})' .format(x, y))
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global mouseCount
    if pressed:
        logging.info('Mouse clicked at ({0}, {1}) with {2}' .format(x, y, button))
    while pressed == True:
        mouseCount += 1
        logging.info(f'mouseClick is at {mouseCount}')
        break

#def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    #print('Mouse scrolled at ({0}, {1}} ({2}, {3})' .format(x, y, dx, dy))
with Listener(on_click = on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the worst part of this code is:

```
    while pressed == True:
        # statements
        break
```

The `break` at the end of the loop will stop the loop from executing a second time, meaning `# statements` will execute exactly once if and only if `pressed == True`.  In other words, this could be rewritten as:

```
    if pressed == True:
        mouseCount += 1
        logging.info(f'mouseClick is at {mouseCount}')
```

Assuming `pressed` will only ever take on the values `True` or `False` (the `pynput` documentation isn’t explicit, but doesn’t suggest otherwise), the `== True` is superfluous, and we can further simply this to:

```
    if pressed:
        mouseCount += 1
        logging.info(f'mouseClick is at {mouseCount}')
```

Now, immediately before this is another `if pressed:` statement, and `pressed` cannot change values between the two, so they can be combined into one `if` statement:

```
    if pressed:
        logging.info('Mouse clicked at ({0}, {1}) with {2}' .format(x, y, button))
        mouseCount += 1
        logging.info(f'mouseClick is at {mouseCount}')
```

## f-strings

You’re using an `f'string'` in the mouseClick log statement, so why the explicit `.format(…)` call:

```
        logging.info('Mouse clicked at ({0}, {1}) with {2}' .format(x, y, button))
```

Why not …

```
        logging.info(f'Mouse clicked at ({x}, {y}) with {button}')
```

… and save 17 characters?

## Logging

Having said that, the `logging` module was written with efficiency in mind.  The logging level can be set to (say) `logging.WARNING` and then `.info(…)` statements will not generate any output.  Unfortunately, time has been wasted interpolating the values into the format string.

A better practise is to pass the values to the logger, and let the logger do the formatting if that logger has the given log level enabled.

```
        logging.info('Mouse clicked at (%d, %d) with %s', x, y, button)
```

Efficiency likely doesn’t matter in this mouse button click counter, so the readability improvement of the f-string approach is probably more important here.  Just be aware that logging can be made more efficient.

## PEP 8

The [Style Guide for Python Coding](https://pep8.org/) has style recommendations that Python code should follow to improve readability by the widest audience.

### Naming

`bumpyWords` are not recommended anywhere in Python.  `snake_case` should be used for function, member, and variable names. (`CapWords` are for class names, and `CAP_WORDS` are for constants)

`mouseCount` violates this naming.  It is a variable, and should be named `mouse_count`.  While we’re renaming it, the computer probably only has one mouse, and perhaps this should be named `mouse_press_count` or `press_count` or `click_count`.

### Assignment -vs- Keywords

`=` is sometimes an operator, and should be surrounded with white space:

```
mouseCount = 0
```

In function calls, it is used as a keyword argument identifier, and no white space should be used, eg) `filename='mouseLog.txt'` and `level=logging.DEBUG`.

You violate the latter with `format = '%(asctime)s: %(message)s'` and `on_click = on_click`.  There should be no space on either side of the `=`.

### Code organization

Source code should be grouped into related chunks.  `import` statements first, global constants and variables, then functions, then mainline code.  `logging.basicConfig(…)` is a statement executed before functions have been defined.  It is out of order.

Often, mainline code is placed in a main-guard, or even a `main()` function called from the main-guard.

## Improved code

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

click_count = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):

    global click_count

    if pressed:
        LOG.info(f'Mouse clicked at ({x}, {y}) with {button}')
        click_count += 1
        LOG.info(f'mouseClick is at {click_count}')

def main():

    logging.basicConfig(filename='mouseLog.txt', level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

    with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
        listener.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Other improvements

Type-hints and doc-strings should be added, to improve readability.  You should learn these.

Modifying global variables using the `global` statement is frowned upon.  This could be replaced with a click counter `class` object, where the `click_count` was a member of the object.  So, you should learn to use classes also.